# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) peripheral app for android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-lowenergy-4.2

I want to write a sample BLE peripheral app for android. I have two nexus 6 devices and I want to use one of them as the central and another one as the  peripheral. For central, I am using the BLE scanner app and I changed that a bit to create bond while the device is selected for establishing the connection. I am looking for some sample code for BLE peripheral on android which can create pairing and bonding with the BLE central. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at this complete android project https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/ble-test-peripheral-android

I used this project to figure out how to create a BLE peripheral and the code was quite easy to understand and follow. (There is also a published app version of this project on Google Play)